# How many arrangements of $s$ selections from $r$ possibilities have at least one skip backwards?

Tags: combinatorics

Say we're selecting $s$ apples and placing them in $r$ different bags (order of placement matters). There are $r^s$ possible orders of placement.

Is there a convenient way to calculate how many distinct arrangements of these include at least one skip backwards? Meaning a placement in a "higher" bag followed by a lower bag with at least one bag in between (bag "c" or "d" followed by bag "a", for example).

Comment: Are you choosing the apples with replacement?  It seems strange for the same apple to go in two different bags.  You need that for $r^s$ to be correct.

Comment: @RossMillikan Since order of placement matters, we can number the apples $1,\ldots,s$. We have $r$ choices of bag for apple $i$, hence $r^s$ possible orders of placement.

Comment: @Tad:  that is fine if we can put more than one apple per bag.

Comment: @RossMillikan I interpreted "different" to mean "distinguishable," and the OP's $r^s$ as confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to start by counting the number which *don't* contain a skip backwards.  In this case, the allowable transitions between successive bag numbers is encoded in the $r\times r$ matrix $A=(a_{ij})$, with $a_{ij}=1$ if $j\ge i-1$ and $0$ otherwise.  The number of valid placement sequences of length $s$, starting with bag $i$ and ending with bag $j$, is the $(i,j)$ entry in the matrix $A^{s-1}$, so the total number of placement sequences is the sum of the elements in $A^{s-1}$.  Thus the solution to the original problem is given by
$$r^s - \mathbf{u}A^{s-1}\mathbf{u}^T,$$
where $u$ is the row vector $(1,\ldots,1)$.

While this seems only semi-tractable, it's worth noting that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ turns out to have a nice closed form.  One can show by induction that 
$$\textrm{charpoly}(A) = \sum_{i\ge 0}(-1)^i\binom{r+1-i}{i}z^{r-i}.$$
It follows that if you fix $r$, then the sequence $\mathbf{u}A^{s-1}\mathbf{u}^T$ satisfies the corresponding linear recurrence.

For example, if $r=7$, the characteristic polynomial is $z^7-7 z^6+15 z^5-10 z^4+z^3$; the corresponding sequence of placement counts with no back-skips is $$7, 34, 143, 560, 2108, 7752, 28101, 100947, 360526, 1282735, 4552624,\ldots$$
which satisfies the recurrence $a_n=7 a_{n-1}-15 a_{n-2}+10a_{n-3}-a_{n-4}$.

Comment: Does this method take account of the "at least one bag between" condition for the definition of a step backward given by OP?

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks - I fixed that!

Comment: Tad: I'd been looking at the incidence matrix you call $A$ and this answer gets to a nice characteristic polynomial, +1.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'll have to learn more math to understand it. Thanks for the opportunity.

Comment: @גלעדברקן A good topic for further study is counting paths in graphs; the matrix $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a natural graph associated with the game.  Feel free to accept the answer if it works for you.